# How to add a id filter in the Strapi call in a nested object?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, axios, strapi

I am trying to send an API get request to Strapi with filter as per below:

```
 let filter = {
    ...cleanObject({
      action_contains: inputValues?.action?.value || null,
      condition_contains: inputValues?.condition?.value || null,
      category_contains: inputValues?.category?.value || null,
      'country.id': inputValues?.country || null,
      'state.id': inputValues?.state || null,
      'city.id': inputValues?.city || null,
     }
```

Where `cleanObject` equals

```
function cleanObject(obj) {
  let propNames = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj);
  for (let i = 0; i < propNames.length; i++) {
    var propName = propNames[i];
    if (obj[propName] === null || obj[propName] === undefined) {
      delete obj[propName];
    }
  }
  return obj;
}
```

The filter then is used later with `axios` which is calling to Strapi

```
  async FIND(filter) {
    try {
      let query
      if (filter) {
        query = qs.stringify(filter)
      }
      let endpoint = `${this.apiEnpoint}${this.service}${query ? `?${query}` : ''}`
      let { data } = await axios.get(endpoint,
        {
          headers: this.headers(this.getToken())
        })
      return { data }
    } catch (error) {
      return { error: this.getErrorMessage(error) }
    }
  }
```

The issue which I am facing is that on Strapi I have the following component:

```
  "address": {
      "type": "component",
      "repeatable": false,
      "component": "address.address"
    },
```

And the component properties areas:

```
{
  "collectionName": "components_address_addresses",
  "info": {
    "name": "address",
    "icon": "address-book",
    "description": ""
  },
  "options": {},
  "attributes": {
    "country": {
      "model": "country"
    },
    "state": {
      "model": "state"
    },
    "city": {
      "model": "city"
    },
    "fullAddress": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "zipCode": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

Problem:

1. If I use `action_contains: inputValues?.action?.value || null,` this generates the query and gets back the results I expect.
2. The part which does not work, I cannot access the `country.id` in the inner object, and not sure what would be the approach for a nested object. When I am sending this to the API Endpoint I am getting back the response:

   {
   "statusCode": 400,
   "error": "Bad Request",
   "message": "Your filters contain a field 'country.id' that doesn't
   appear on your model definition nor it's relations"
   }

The API call itself looks like this:

`http://localhost:8080/real-estate-listings/count?_where%5Bcountry.id%5D=602e0e07dd3e24308f9f1fb0`

What I have tried:
I tried to add the `'country.id': inputValues?.country || null,` to several combinations like `address.country.id`, replacing dot with ?, adding _eq in the end of it. Tried to Read Strapi Documentation, which confused me a bit more.

**Question:**
How should I change the API call in order for me to filter by the country id in the object nested element?

Note: The full code is much larger, so only parts that I see related have been provided. I hope that is enough.

Technologies used: MongoDb, Next.js, Strapi.